# Insert a character every n characters in a string from right to left?

Tags: regex

Is there a simple regular expression that would insert a character, say a colon :, every n characters, say 2, from right to left in a string?

For example...

059 -> 0:59

14598 -> 1:45:98

340001 -> 34:00:01

Comment: Please show the regex pattern you tried and specify regex flavor.

Comment: For this particular case, you may use [`(?=\d{2}$|\d{4}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/jk7kN9/1) and replace each match with a `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment is supporting [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can use a lookahead to check for one or more of any two characters ahead until `$` end of line at any place between character (use `\B` a non [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to trigger the lookahead only between word characters) and replace with colon.

```
\B(?=(?:..)+$)
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jf2zDT/1)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific, I am using the String.replaceAll() method in Java. How would I use this regex with this method?

Comment: @SpamSpam [`String Str = new String("059\n14598\n340001"); Str = Str.replaceAll("(?m)\\B(?=(?:..)+$)", ":");`](https://www.ideone.com/fork/LfTSyl)

Comment: I meant if it was just one of the numbers specifically, String str = new String("059") -> Str = Str.replaceAll(...)

Comment: @SpamSpam Yes, you can use this for every of your testcases. [See demo (without multiline flag): `Str = Str.replaceAll("\\B(?=(?:..)+$)", ":");`](https://www.ideone.com/fork/6bBoqM)

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. Thank you. Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a "2*N arbitrary characters" lookahead:

```
s/(?=(?:.{2})+$)/:/g
```